CSH loop over results from grep not giving desired outcome
I want to loop over the lines as output by grep cmd from a file. The lines follow a format where there will be a word matched / not matched by the grep and then some other word that some other program will have to do something with. There is expectation that appropriate subdirs are available.
cat > fridge << BYE
 apple good
 banana bad
 cherry good
BYE

foreach ln (`grep good fridge`)
  echo "line is= ${ln}"
  set fruit= `echo ${ln} | cut -d' ' -f1`
  set status= `echo ${ln} | cut -d' ' -f2`
  echo "fruit= ${fruit} is ${status}"
  pushd ${fruit}_dir
  #<do something>
  popd
end

I first expect to see the line printed.
Example : line= apple good
But I only see apple. That's mistake #1
Then there is error about the variable. That's mistake #2.
I expect following output
line= apple good
fruit= apple is good
Some stuff from do something with apple
line= cherry good
fruit= cherry is good
Some stuff from do something with cherry

But it is not working.
line is= apple
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.


You know about http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ ? Your basic problem is right at the top,  Note how % foreach ln ("a b" "c d" "e f" )
? echo $ln
? enddoes produce the "line oriented" output, where as if you remove the quotes, you get "word oriented" output. Its a feature (-;? (The?` marks are the part of the 2ndary prompt from csh. you'll need to remove those and put stuff on their own proper single lines.) Good luck.

The right way to write a script that does what the one in your question appears to be trying to do when you use csh as your login shell is:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r ln; do
  echo "line is= ${ln}"
  fruit=${ln% *}
  status=${ln#* }
  echo "fruit= ${fruit} is ${status}"
  cd "${fruit}_dir"
  #<do something>
  cd -
done < <(grep good fridge)

i.e. don't write a csh script, write a bash script and call it from csh. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ and the many other articles you'll find if you google "csh why not" for the reasons to not try to write scripts using csh.
Assuming you don't really need a variable to hold the whole input line, the above would be more efficient and robust if it were written as:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r fruit status; do
  echo "fruit= ${fruit} is ${status}"
  cd "${fruit}_dir"
  #<do something>
  cd -
done < <(awk '$2 == "good"' fridge)

Your here-document populating fridge has a potential problem, btw - it's putting a leading blank at the start of each line so when your code tries to split the line at a blank, it may stumble over that leading one. You should probably do this instead:
cat > fridge << BYE
apple good
banana bad
cherry good
BYE

or you could do the following with bash, no idea about csh, where the leading space on each line is a tab:
cat > fridge <<- BYE
        apple good
        banana bad
        cherry good
BYE

